# I am making a d3.js graph as a csv file How should I manipulate the data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my code.

```
d3.csv("/static/domain.csv", function(error, data) {

 dataset=data
 
        var diameter = 800;
        var format = d3.format(",d"),
      color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeSet3)

        var bubble = d3.pack(dataset)
            .size([diameter, diameter])
            .padding(1.5);


        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", diameter)
            .attr("height", diameter)
            .attr("class", "bubble");

        var nodes = d3.hierarchy(dataset)
            .sum(function(d) { return d.Count; });

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(bubble(nodes).descendants())
            .enter()
            .filter(function(d){
                return  !d.children
            })
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            });

        node.append("title")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.Name + ": " + d.Count;
            });

        node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", function(d) {
                return d.r;
            })
            .style("fill", function(d,i) {
                return color(i);
            });

        node.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".2em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.data.Name.substring(0, d.r / 3);
            })
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", function(d){
                return d.r/5;
            })
            .attr("fill", "white");

        node.append("text")
            .attr("dy", "1.3em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.data.Count;
            })
            .attr("font-family",  "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT")
            .attr("font-size", function(d){
                return d.r/5;
            })
            .attr("fill", "white");

        d3.select(self.frameElement)
            .style("height", diameter + "px");


});
```

and I got error

> visiteddomain.js:52 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'substring' of undefined
> at SVGTextElement. (visiteddomain.js:52)
> at SVGTextElement. (d3.v6.min.js:2)
> at xn.each (d3.v6.min.js:2)
> at xn.text (d3.v6.min.js:2)
> at visiteddomain.js:51
> at d3.v6.min.js:2
> at d3.v6.min.js:2
> at r (d3.v6.min.js:2)
> at parse (d3.v6.min.js:2)
> at d3.v6.min.js:2

The original dataset looked like this

```
dataset = {
            "children": [{"Name":"Olives","Count":4319},
                {"Name":"Tea","Count":4159},
                {"Name":"Mashed Potatoes","Count":2583},
                {"Name":"Boiled Potatoes","Count":2074},
                {"Name":"Milk","Count":1894},
                {"Name":"Chicken Salad","Count":1809},
                {"Name":"Vanilla Ice Cream","Count":1713},
                {"Name":"Cocoa","Count":1636},
                {"Name":"Lettuce Salad","Count":1566},
                {"Name":"Lobster Salad","Count":1511},
                {"Name":"Chocolate","Count":1489},
                {"Name":"Apple Pie","Count":1487},
                {"Name":"Orange Juice","Count":1423},
                {"Name":"American Cheese","Count":1372},
                {"Name":"Green Peas","Count":1341},
                {"Name":"Assorted Cakes","Count":1331},
                {"Name":"French Fried Potatoes","Count":1328},
                {"Name":"Potato Salad","Count":1306},
                {"Name":"Baked Potatoes","Count":1293},
                {"Name":"Roquefort","Count":1273},
                {"Name":"Stewed Prunes","Count":1268}]
        };
```

and my csv file

```
,Name,Count 
0,google.com,43 
1,stackoverflow.com,20 
2,tistory.com,12
3,github.com,11 
4,observablehq.com,10 
5,ocks.org,8 
6,youtube.com,6
7,okky.kr,6 
8,naver.com,5 
9,plnkr.co,2
```

Comment: In d3 v6, `d3.csv(url, callback)` has been replaced by `d3.csv(url).then(callback)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just replace `d.data.Name` with `d.Name`. Same with  `d.data.Count`